# Why doesn't the verb need to have "s" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> He has never seen his mother make a cake.

Why is *make* correct? I got corrected because I wrote *makes.*

Why isn't "He has never seen his mother **makes** a cake" a correct sentence?

Comment: It's because "make a cake" is a non-finite verb phrase headed by the plain (infinitival) form of the verb "make". A non-finite VP is required because it is complement of another verb, in this case "seen". Note that "His mother make a cake" cannot stand alone as an independent main clause in the same way that "His mother makes cakes" can

Comment: @BillJ thank you for your advice. The reason is "make" complements "seen" in this sentence.

Comment: Yes, that's right. When two or more verbs occur consecutively, even if they have an intervening noun, as in your example, the second and subsequent verbs are always non-finite, such as infinitival or gerund-participle (the _ing_ form).

Comment: @BillJ Thank you so much for the explanation. I could understand my mistake better.

Answer (score 3):

"*He has never seen his mother make a cake"* is a correct sentence.

Here ***make*** is an infinitive without ***to***.

> The infinitive is used without **to** after certain verbs like **bid, let,
>   make, see, hear, need, dare** etc. (*[EnglishGrammar.org](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/)*)

Infinitives come in two types: the **to infinitive** and the **bare infinitive** (infinitive without **to**). Either form of the infinitive is the base form of the verb, which does not inflect according to the tense or the number or person of the subject.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Would you please let me know why "make" used without "s" in this sentence?

Comment: Infinitives are two types - **to infinitive** and **bare infinitive** ( infinitive without **to**). Either form of infinitive is the base form of verbs but it does not inflect in accordance with the tense or number or person of subjects.

Comment: Thank you again for helping me. I carefully read your explanation and the link you sent.